# Приложение для отправки push-уведомления

Tags: android, linux, windows, ios, push-уведомления

Хочу написать приложение, для отправки push-уведомлений(сообщений).

Его суть: открываю приложение, нажимаю кнопку "отправиться push-уведомление", записываю в него какой-нибудь текст, и оно отправляется всем, у кого есть это приложение.

Суть вопроса: с чего начать? Приложение хочу написать под Windows, iOS и Android (и хочу под Linux).
Подтолкните в нужном направлении: статьями, советами и прочим.

Comment: Начать с выяснения, что такое push-уведомления.

Comment: Открываете приложение, нажимаете отправить пуш, пошел запрос на ваш сервер (можете использовать сторонние сервисы), сервер генерит все что надо, отправляет в APNS (в случае с iOS), а там уже пуш дойдет до получателей. Читайте документацию =)

Comment: для послылки уведомлений можно использовать Firebase. Например тут https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/messaging/package-summary описан вариант для андроид а тут https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/ios/firebasemessaging/api/reference/Classes - для ios.